# Reading from Optane-SSD without support

Tags: windows, hard-drive, drivers, ssd, storage

I have an M.2 NVMe SSD with an Intel Optane H10 accelerator on it. My old mainboard had Optane support but my new one doesn't. It shows up as 2 drives, one is the 32GB Optane accellerator and the other one the 1TB SSD. Is there a way I can access my files on said SSD? I sadly couldn't find any online resources on that.

The actual storage on the module is NAND flash and as far as I've understood it, storing data on it works pretty much the same as on regular NVMe drives. So why does it show as an "invalid partition" in most partitioning software? Is there a driver to fix this issue? (Might it work on linux? - i have to get an external drive to test this, since my linux laptop doesn't have a free M.2/NVMe slot)

Comment: See if this Intel post assists you:  https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Optane-Memory/Need-help-recovering-data-from-Optane-accelerated-secondary/td-p/557710

Comment: @John this sadly does not help with my issue, since it's about a completely different problem. I don't have issues with my OS or the boot process. I just want my personal data off of the drive, without having to look for an Optane compatible system to boot from it and manually copy. Is there a way to access the SSD, disregarding the Optane functionality?

Comment: You may be out of luck then,

Comment: The actual storage on the module is NAND flash and as far as I've understood it, storing data on it works pretty much the same as on regular NVMe drives. So why does it show as an "invalid partition" in most partitioning software?

Comment: I am not sure. Optane is very specialized, so it does not work the very same as a regular SSD

Comment: Try to install the [Samsung NVMe Driver](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/).

Comment: @harrymc The device is made by Intel, so Samsung drivers won't work

Comment: *I just want my personal data off of the drive* The assumption there's any retrievable "personal data" in an Optane drive is flat out wrong. Even if there were user accessible files in that drive (there's NONE, it's a file system that only the Intel controller understands), considering it's purpose is to accelerate r/w processes what you would find there (again, if you could but you don't) would be copies of system and programs files, not "personal data".

Comment: @ChanganAuto There are 2 different storage media on the M.2 package. On is a 32GB chip, the other a 1TB one. I know there is no data on the 32GB one, since this is the one used for Optane. But there is data on the 1TB chip. But it fails to partition

Comment: It doesn't "fail to partition", it's simply unreadable (ENCRYPTED) if not in the optane mode with the Intel RST controller and there's no way to access it otherwise, period. This as been answered and comment too many times already.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can access my files on said SSD?

**No, there isn't, because there should be NO files in there if you've been using in the "RAID-like with special features" that is the Optane configuration.** The small SSD is there for cache only.

No that you "disengaged" the drives you can actually use that drive like any other SSD. And no, contrary to what was previously commented - *Optane is very specialized, so it does not work the very same as a regular SSD* - **it actually is very much like any other SSD**, just optimized for the purpose. Many users have in the past selected AHCI drive mode and use the previously not-user-accessible small SSD to install an OS.

Comment: This is an Intel (!) SSD with an Optane H10 accelerator on it. I am not talking about reading files from the Optane memory but about retrieving files from the same device, working around the Optane functionality. I am talking about the NAND flash I wanna read from.

Comment: Why downvotes? If you're convinced it's possible show how.

Comment: @Caeleste NAND flash is a characteristic; "Optane memory" is not something distinct. It's just an SSD optimized for use as CACHE in a RAID-like configuration. Other than that it's a drive like any other, not 2 distinct things as you're implying. You can use it as intended with "Intel RST" in which case **you won't see it (the "accelerator" part)** or you can enable AHCI instead and then the "accelerator" can be used as an independent drive. There's no magic here and it's (mostly) a marketing gimmick. When used as "optane" whatever is written to it can ONLY be understood by the Intel controller

Comment: (...) Reason why it's an "invalid partition" when the drives are decoupled. Again, **you can use it like any other drive after clearing the partition table and creating one or more new partitions** but **NOTHING from it's former usage under "optane" is user accessible**, OS is immaterial, how the Intel controller actually works is NOT public knowledge, end of story.